# user login but token not changing before refresh with JWT auth in angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, jwt

i create auth with jwt in angular

in my service api

```
login(body: any) {
  return this._http.post(this.apiURL + 'login', body, {
    observe: 'body',
  }
}
```

in my login function

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log(data);
          this.successMessage = data;
          this.userService.getUserName().subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              this.userChange.next(data.data);
              localStorage.setItem('displayName', data.data.displayName);
              if (data.data.emailVerified != true) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/email-verification');
              }
              if (data.data.kewirusType == 'user') {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/projects/all-project')
              } else if (data.data.kewirusType == 'admin') {
                localStorage.setItem('kewirusType', data.data.kewirusType);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('kewirusType'));
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/admin/users-list');
              }
            },
          )
        },
        error => {
          this.loading = false
          console.log(error.error.message[0]);
          this.errorMessage = error.error.message[0];
        }
      )});
    
  }
```

so when i first login, let's say i use admin account, then i logout, and then i login with user account, it gives admin account not user account. and the token

here's admin token before logout

[image]

here's user account after login, it return the same token

[image]

here's after i refresh the page, the token changing

[image]

i have talked to my backend, but he said that it's from my code on frontend not his, but i can't find the problem, does anyone knows why this is happening?

EDIT

here's my api calls for user detail

```
 getUserName() {
    return this._http.get<User[]>(this.apiURL + 'auth/user')
  }
```

after couple hours looking for the problems, i believe that this has to do with changing header authorization token, cause it's not changing after user is logout using their other account. is there any way to refresh the headers while logout?

Comment: Do you use `localStorage.clear();` on your `logOut` function ?

Comment: can you show the code for sending the token in the request, for the getUserName request for example?

Comment: i've added that

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage.clear();` on your `logout()` function.

Comment: i did that, but still not working, i also did `removeItem('userData')`

Comment: Place the `this.userChange.next(data.data);` after the next line set localstorage `localStorage.setItem('displayName', data.data.displayName);` in your login function and check if it works?

Comment: actually that userChange i'll delete it cause i'm not using it

Comment: the token is different though, but in headers authorization token is the same idk y

Comment: It seems that its the backend problem.

Comment: maybe, but i have api docs, and in api docs everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out, it's because the `auth-interceptor` here's my code

```
getToken() {
  return this.userData.data.token;
}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  if (this.getToken() != null) {
    const clonedReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.getToken())
    });
    return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
      tap(
        succ => {
          },
        err => {
          if (err.status == 401) {
            this.getToken();
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
          } else if (err.status == 403) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/forbidden');
          }
        }
      )
    )
  }
  else {
    return next.handle(req.clone());
  }
}
```

and i found this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhelpers%2Fjwt.interceptor.ts

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  // add authorization header with jwt token if available
  let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
  if (currentUser && currentUser.data.token) {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.data.token}`
      }
    });
  }
  return next.handle(request);
}
```

then it works, idk y if anybody can explain it that'd be helpful